# prepareForSegue send Pdfs error - could not cast

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, pdf

I want to ask how to send correctly pdfs between a tableView and a webView.
For this I have 2 strings with names of the rows in tableView and another one with the names of pdfs that I wanna to transfer

I've been following the respective steps from a tutorial , but I'm getting this error in the `prepareForSegue` method:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x1079f1a18) to 'NSNumber' (0x106ab4b88).
```

Error is in this line:

```
var seleccion = sender as! Int
```

Error is coming when I click a row in the `tableView` , So the pdf could not be showed

My code :

```
class PersonajesHistoricosViewController: UIViewController {


var arregloPdfs = ["jobs1.pdf" , "disney1.pdf","jobs1.pdf"]

var arregloGanadores : [String] = [String]()
var pdfSeleccionado:Int = 0


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    arregloGanadores = ["Steve Jobs" , "Walt Disney" , "Arnold Schwarzenegger"]



}


//****************TABLE VIEW*************************
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    //make sure you use the relevant array sizes
    return arregloGanadores.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell :UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell
    //Aqui podria hacer referencia a otro array con nombres en especifico para cada uno de los pdfs
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.arregloGanadores[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:"Libro.jpg")

    return cell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    pdfSeleccionado = indexPath.row

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("haciaVisorPdf", sender: pdfSeleccionado)


}



//Por si quiere cambiar el ancho de cada renglon o celda
//   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
//
//        return 150
//    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    // HERE IS THE ERROR
    var seleccion = sender as! Int


    if segue.identifier == "haciaVisorPdf"
    {


        var visorPdf: WebView = segue.destinationViewController as! WebView

        visorPdf.nombreArchivo = self.arregloPdfs[seleccion]


    }    

}
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

class WebView: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!   

var nombreArchivo:String = ""   


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    println("\(nombreArchivo)")


    zoom()
    mostrarPdf()

}

func zoom () {

    webView.scalesPageToFit = true


}


func mostrarPdf(){


    //Paso 1 : conseguir direccion en tu bundle de tu archivo pdf
    var direccionPdf = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(nombreArchivo, ofType: "pdf")!)

    println(direccionPdf)

    if let pdfData = NSData(contentsOfURL: direccionPdf!) {

        cargarDatos(pdfData)


    }

    else {

    }

}

func cargarDatos(datosDePdf:NSData) {


    self.webView.loadData(datosDePdf, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: nil)


}
}
```

Comment: Why you not use the global variable `pdfSeleccionado` instead of pass the index in the `prepareForSegue`?

Comment: Thanks for answering bro . It's due to I need more time to practice and understand how XCode works . But it's just matter of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple :

> **sender:** The object that initiated the segue. You might use this parameter to perform different actions based on which control (or other object) initiated the segue.

---

> Segues can be triggered from multiple sources, so use the information in the segue and sender parameters to disambiguate between different logical paths in your app. For example, if the segue originated from a table view, the sender parameter would identify the cell that the user clicked. You could use that information to set the data on the destination view controller.

Your problem is that the `sender` isn't used for what you want. But you have a global variable `pdfSeleccionado` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` with your `indexPath.row` , you can use it instead to try to pass it in the `prepareForSegue`, because you first enter in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and then you execute the segue manually , something like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){   

    if segue.identifier == "haciaVisorPdf" {
       var visorPdf: WebView = segue.destinationViewController as! WebView
       visorPdf.nombreArchivo = self.arregloPdfs[pdfSeleccionado]
    }
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: It helps a lot !! Thanks 
Now a new error is released in webView (class)

In the function mostrarpdf() {

Comment: Error looks like this : jobs1.pdf
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Ok no problem if the  answer solve your question please accept it. It could be helpful for another one

Comment: It's done bro. Could you give me some help according to the new error?

Comment: What's printing in the method?

Comment: func mostrarPdf(){
     
        var direccionPdf = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(nombreArchivo, ofType: "pdf")!)
        
        println(direccionPdf)
        
        if let pdfData = NSData(contentsOfURL: direccionPdf!) {
            
            cargarDatos(pdfData)
            
            
        }
            
        else {
            
        }


Function is to show each pdf at the moment we click each cell